# How can I make the Telerik progress bar work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a Telerik progress bar in my project:

```
<telerik:RadProgressManager ID="RadProgressManager" Runat="server" />
<telerik:RadProgressArea ID="RadProgressArea" Runat="server"></telerik:RadProgressArea>   
<asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" text="Submit" />
```

On button click I try to run this method:

```
private void MethodWhichUpdatesTheProgressContext(UploadedFile file, int countFile)
{
     const int total = 100;
     RadProgressContext ProgressContex = RadProgressContext.Current;
     ProgressContex.SecondaryTotal = "100";

     for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
     {
         ProgressContex.CurrentOperationText = "Uploading zip file percentage " + i.ToString();                

         if (!Response.IsClientConnected)
         {                    
             break;
         }

         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
     }
}
```

Project builds without any errors but progress doesn't change.
How do I properly fire the progress bar animation?
If I put this progress bar on control, it can effect this?

Answer (score 1):

Increment the **ProgressContex.SecondaryValue** or **ProgressContex.SecondaryPercent** inside the loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        ProgressContex.CurrentOperationText = "Uploading zip file percentage " + i.ToString();
        ProgressContex.SecondaryValue = i.ToString();
        ProgressContex.SecondaryPercent = i.ToString();
    }
```

#### See Also:

> [RadProgressArea Custom Progress](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/upload-progress-customprogress.html)

Comment: It works on simple page like this. If I put this progress bar on control, it can effect this?